# Some files not showing up in file manager, but definitely are there

Tags: files, filemanager, data-loss

I have got the most strange problem, I downloaded 4 images yesterday, then cut and paste them using Nautilus into a sub-folder of my `Documents` area. I then closed Nautilus and went on with my normal business.

However later on I needed to send the images to someone so I went into the folder with the images using Nautilus, but they weren't there! And this is where it gets even stranger, the images show up, though not their thumbnails, when I use Firefox's file chooser for instance, or another program's file chooser, in fact if I open the Image Viewer and then use its file chooser to find them I can open and view them perfectly fine.

The other odd thing is that Nautilus half knows they are there, because my first reaction was to think that my computer just ate them somehow, so I redownloaded them, and pasted them into the folder where the previous ones should have been. Nautilus asked me if I wanted to replace the old with the new and it even showed me the correct thumbnails this time!

I am also able to see that the files are present in Terminal using commands such as `ls` and `tree`, I can also `cat` the contents so the files are readable and everything.

Here is the `stat` output for one of them:

```
 stat DSCF2365.jpg
  File: 'DSCF2365.jpg'
  Size: 2213598     Blocks: 4328       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 29623172    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  totoro)   Gid: ( 1000/  totoro)
Access: 2016-08-02 23:39:15.651962645 +0100
Modify: 2016-08-02 22:51:26.613739542 +0100
Change: 2016-08-02 23:12:04.540134139 +0100
 Birth: -
```

It was suggested to me that this could be because of a filesystem error, so I ran `fsck` on boot and this was the output in `syslog`:

```
Aug  3 10:54:45 <Computer-Name> kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root ro noprompt fsck.mode=force
Aug  3 10:54:45 <Computer-Name> systemd-fsck[2176]: fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Aug  3 10:54:45 <Computer-Name> systemd-fsck[2176]: /dev/sda1: 28 files, 3120/130812 clusters
Aug  3 10:54:45 <Computer-Name> systemd-fsck[2191]: /dev/sda2: 301/62496 files (22.6% non-contiguous), 129379/249856 blocks
Aug  3 10:54:45 <Computer-Name> kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root ro noprompt fsck.mode=force
Aug  3 10:55:00 <Computer-Name> /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3200]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root ro noprompt fsck.mode=force
Aug  3 10:55:31 <Computer-Name> /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3341]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root ro noprompt fsck.mode=force
```

I will soon do the same checks from a LiveUSB, when I have done that I will update this question with the information on how that went. If this is useful to anyone the output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0   244M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0   465G  0 part
  ├─ubuntu--gnome--vg-root   252:0    0 461.2G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1 252:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So I am using LVM. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20. What could the problem be and what shall I do about it? The place to which I downloaded the second batch of the same files still shows them (my `Downloads` folder).

**Information Update:**

I have now tried installing `nemo`, and the issue is also present there.

And there is something even more interesting that I have discovered, if I search for the file names using `nautilus` and `nemo`, they do come up in the search results, their thumbnails show correctly, and I am able to open them!

The output of `blkid` is:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="9936-E7FF" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="8054dcbf-83e1-4d42-bd5c-7a7ec2b5b563"
/dev/sda2: UUID="a1ee7705-4528-434a-8aca-54486d48093d" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="56930149-d506-4773-9b31-b9ab1fa3aed8"
/dev/sda3: UUID="4Fa3uc-So0F-4d6c-ePh9-Eb09-JMl1-30k45r" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="3816306f-068b-4385-b2a9-a67e320d7b4a"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root: UUID="925ad182-e013-4b66-8b0c-18e549a28f82" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1: UUID="97995176-acae-4d9a-bb88-08adefd556df" TYPE="swap"
```

If I use the `mv` command to rename the file, it still does not show.

**I have now looked again and the files have reappeared** along with a lot of other files which were missing from that folder! I hope them reappearing hasn't made any others disappear, is there any way I can check? What could be causing this?

Comment: Is the problem reproducible?  
Is it manifesting for other files?
What happens if you clone the files on the same path to a new filename?
Do they then show on Nautilus?
Have you tried installing Nemo to see what that shows?
What filesystem are you using?

Comment: @DanglingPointer: I don't know, I expect so, I hope no more files on my system have gone missing, but I'm sure that I had more pictures in that folder than are showing there now... The files still haven't turned up, I will keep an eye out to see if it happens with any more new files. I will try what you said and update my question. I have tried Nemo and updated my question.

Comment: @DanglingPointer: The `mv` command doesn't change anything but the name, and I have updated my question with my filesystem information.

Comment: @DanglingPointer: The files just magicked back! I've updated my question.

Comment: Cause could be an error in the journaling that got fixed.

Comment: Was Nautilus showing the "loading" symbol while trying to access said folder? I sometimes encounter the issue on an External drive, it shows "loading" forever and hides one or two files. However, when I close it and open it again, they re-appear.

Comment: Whatever the gist of a problem is, report a bug against nautilus. Given that files shows up with `ls`, everything is fine with file system either, it's just a bug in a file manager.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: But the problem is also present in the Nemo file manager... So isn't it going to be something more central than that?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I'd rather guess they're using the same library of something, and that library have a bug. Unless you have an idea what library could that be, report a bug against nautilus, devs would figure it out.

Comment: Logging a bug against Nautilus could prove futile if it isn't reproducible.
Do so anyway, you never know unless you try...
Here's a drastic-last-resort option.... If you are worried about the integrity or usability of your environment, I suggest you back up your files externally and blow away completely your OS.  Then re-install Ubuntu, perhaps try a CoW filesystem like BTRFS, ZFS, or F2FS (if you're using an SSD).

Comment: Have you tried Thunar or PCmanfm? are those files shown on them?

Comment: I have a bug, which might be related, and already reported it (some years ago, now - still open), with Nautilus and Images. For me, changing the directory and coming back in solved the issue, so it is probably a different thing, on the other side, I only observed it with images.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this issue so I guess that it should be closed.

Comment: I have this exact same problem: the file was created by pdfarranger, it shows up with `ls`, with nautilus, but not with nemo. `ls -l` doesn't show any difference between files that do and don't show up in nemo.

Answer (score 25):

Had the issue of files/folders not appearing in File Manager, but being listed in terminal.

Solved it by doing:
*File Manager > View > Reload*
(shortcut: *Ctrl+R*).

Comment: +1 This helped! Is there any explanation why File Manager may show this odd behavior?

Comment: files were visible in terminal, but not in Desktop. Solved it by pressing - `Alt + F2` and add `r` (restarting GNome). This helped me !

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you open a terminal, cd to the directory in question, and run "ls -la". That is the least likely to lie to you.  You will see all files, and their permissions.

A GUI file manager like  nautilus or such is a few steps away from the full, accurate truth about what is there and what are its properties. That file manger may have "features" or "simplifying enhancements" that prevent you from seeing everything that is there.

There may be a bug, but I'm betting on the "simplifying enhancement" aspect.  I've been using Nautilus for 10 years and often I can't find anything anymore. They have made it so "helpful" it is almost useless.  You  can't even launch a terminal out of it anymore.

If your terminals lack beauty, consider installing "terminology" from the enlightenment project.  There's some eye candy. I cant quite believe it.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just been having this problem in Nemo and a workaround is to change the view. I usually use list view so I changed to icon view and back. This forced a refresh which the actual Refresh command didn’t.