# Nautilus file browser not showing all files unless refresh (continually says "loading")

Tags: nautilus

I have a small but frustrating problem: often, when I open a directory by navigating around nautilus and double clicking, it will show some of, but not all of the files I know are there. In the bottom right hand corner of the window, it will say "loading":

[image: "loading..." image]

There aren't that many files (directly in the dir; there are maybe 100 in a folder inside that dir), and the total size of the dir is 15MB anyway. There are a few ~3MB gifs and 3MB text files, but all totaling less than 15MB.

I've found that if I click that stop loading button, and then hit F5 to refresh, the files all appear.

I believe [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806491/some-files-not-showing-up-in-file-manager-but-definitely-are-there?newreg=97c769eb9baa43659e31c2c355602e1c) was asking about the same problem, but it was closed for some reason. The solutions given are "refresh the browser" (a workaround, not a solution) and "list the files in the terminal to see that they're really there" (we both already knew they're there).

This really can't be a solution though, because it seriously slows down my workflow. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and this happens on both my machines with it (they're both decently fast).

Any suggestions or things I could try?

Comment: It is buggy behavior that persists in Ubuntu 18.10, which uses the same version of nautilus. Might or might not be solved in Ubuntu 19.04, where an up to date version of nautilus will be used.

Comment: I am experiencing this in Ubuntu 20.04. It is quite frustrating and I can't find anything about this issue elsewhere. I think the workaround of toggling the view between list and icons is the quickest and most convenient.

Comment: Nautilus has so many problems (like not being able to sort search results) that I just stopped caring and migrated to Nemo.

Comment: @australis nice at least that works